Is there a Moiré pattern present in this plot, as circular orbits in a surface created by a complex sequence represented in space
I was checking some plots I made recently, and a friend pointed out that he saw a Moiré pattern in one of them, and I was explaining him that it wasn't a Moiré pattern trying to interest him in the math behind the plot without success.
But then I realized that maybe he was referring to it as an effect in the plot that can be described and justified mathematically.
The image is this:

If you zoom in you will see circular orbits looking like these Morié pattern:

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/97/Moire_Lines.svg
The plot is made with these cartesian coordinate sequences:
$$\vec{\mathbf{X_n}}=(u_n,v_n,w_n)=(u_n,v_n,f(u_n,v_n))$$
$$\omega=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{T_o}}$$
$$
r_k=
\begin{cases}
0 &  k  < 0 \\
r_{k-1}+\Delta r_o & \space k \geq 0 \text{ and } k \equiv 0 \pmod{M} \\
r_{k-1} & \space   k > 0 \text{ and } k \not\equiv 0 \pmod{M}
\end{cases}
$$
$$Z_n=r_n\omega^n=u_n+ i v_n$$
$$\overline{Z_n}=r_n\omega^{-n}=u_n- i v_n$$
The color $C_n$ is a coolwarm colormap with $M_c$ colors, in this example using the index $n$ directly:
$$C_n \equiv n \pmod{M_{c}}$$
$M_c=2584$ and $T_o =\frac{1618033988749895}{10^{15}}\approx \varphi$
$$\Omega_o=\frac{2 \pi}{T_o}$$
$$u_n=\frac{1}{2}(Z_n+\overline{Z_n})=r_n cos(\Omega_o n)$$
$$v_n=\frac{1}{2i}(Z_n-\overline{Z_n})=r_n sin(\Omega_o n)$$
$$w_n=\frac{log(|Z_n|)}{log(2)}$$
